# Executing several script in several locations at once

Tags: linux, bash

I am experimenting with this form:

```
eval "parallel -j 1 /home/user/dl/"{1..60}"/111/23/serial.sh;"
```

The problem: I have 60 scripts in 60 folders and I want to execute them one by one, also I must make sure that this works on the first try

Will this command execute all the scripts one by one? and will `eval` find all the correct directories for the scripts?

Answer (score 0):

This is not correct `parallel` syntax. Parallel is specifically designed to execute multiple jobs at a time. To execute them one by one, just use

```
for file in /home/user/dl/{1..60}/111/23/serial.sh
do
  "$file"
done
```